# http.get loop to download list of files

Tags: node.js

I want to get http.get to download a list of image files.
I have a for loop to go through the list and fill  variable file_savedest with a string that represents the save location.
So http.get gets called on each loop iteration, how do I feed the file_savedest into http.get so it know the file to download and save.

```
    var file_savedest = dir+"/"+iname;

    http.get(options, function(res){
        var imagedata = '';
        res.setEncoding('binary');

        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            imagedata += chunk
        });

        res.on('end', function(){
            fs.writeFile(file_savedest, imagedata, 'binary', function(err){
                if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("File:" + file_savedest + " saved");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29):

```
(function(file_savedest){
    http.get(options, function(res){
        var imagedata = '';
        res.setEncoding('binary');

        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            imagedata += chunk
        });

        res.on('end', function(){
            fs.writeFile(file_savedest, imagedata, 'binary', function(err){
                if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("File:" + file_savedest + " saved");
                }
            });
        });
    });
}(dir+"/"+iname));
```