# node.js loop through array to write files

Tags: arrays, node.js, loops, http-get, streamwriter

I've been working through a few [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310990/nodejs-lost-data-when-using-loop-for-download-many-files), also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343951/http-get-loop-to-download-list-of-files) of looping through array to http.get data from a variety of sources. I understand that nodeJS is working asynchronously which is allowing the files to be written empty or with incomplete data, but I can't seem to get past this point.

**Problem: calls are made, files are built but the files are always empty**

**Goal: loop through an array to create files locally from the sites data.** Here is what I've got so far:

```
var file_url = 'http://js.arcgis.com/3.8amd/js/esri/',
    DOWNLOAD_DIR = './esri/',
    esriAMD = [ '_coremap.js', 'arcgis/csv.js'];

function readFile(callback) {
  if (esriAMD.length > 0) {
    var setFile = esriAMD.shift(),
        file_name = url.parse(file_url).pathname.split('/').pop(),
        trial = setFile.split('/').pop(),
        file = fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR + trial);

    http.get(file_url + esriAMD, function(res) {
      res.on('data', function(data) {
        file.write(data);
        console.log(setFile + ' has been written successfully');
      });
      res.on('end', function(){
        console.log(setFile + ' written, moving on');
        console.log(esriAMD.length);
        readFile(callback);
      });
      //readFile(callback);
    });
  } else {
    callback();
  }
}
readFile(function() {
  console.log("reading finishes");
});
```

Any insight would really help.

thanks,

Comment: try using simpler modules such as `request` were you can pipe the file directly to the stream.

Comment: What problems are you seeing with your current solution?

Comment: This "http.get(file_url + esriAMD..." should be " http.get(file_url + file_name...", right? Also, I would create the file inside the callback for the http.get() rather than outside. It should not matter in your case since you don't call readFile() again until res.on('end') but logically it would make more sense inside of it.

Comment: @Phoenix I tried http.request and got a 'socket hang up' error, any thoughts?

Comment: @HectorCorrea thanks you pointed me in the right direction, I was passing in the wrong variable. I should have been passing in 'setFile'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution: I was passing the wrong variable into the `http.get`**

Working code:

```
var file_url = 'http://.....',
DOWNLOAD_DIR = './location/';
esriAMD = ['one', 'two', 'three'..0;

function readFile(callback) {
if(esriAMD.length > 0) {
    var setFile = esriAMD.shift(),
    file_name = url.parse(setFile).pathname.split('/').pop(),
    trial = setFile.split('/').pop(),
        file = fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR + trial);

    http.get(file_url + setFile, function(res){
        res.on('error', function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
        res.on('data', function(data){
            file.write(data);
            console.log(setFile + ' started');
        });
        res.on('end', function(){ 
            console.log(setFile + ' completed, moving on');
        });
    });
} else {
    callback();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var esriAMD = [....];
...
function readFile(callback) {
    ...
    http.get(file_url + esriAMD, function(res) {
        ...
```

concatenating strings with arrays may yield unexpected results.

you want to make sure that

- you know what URLs your program is accessing
- your program deals with error situations (where the fsck is `res.on('error', ...)`?)